# is it possible that we can share files and folders from workgroup system to domain system

Tags: networking

I'm a student I have created a server on vmware (windows server 2003) and installed active directory, DNS, Dhcp. and in virtual box two client xp systems and added both client system in domain. now i have to access my local software and files from my workgroup system but i am not able to access those files from Domain system. is there any way to access from workgroup to domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can map to shares as usual from the Tools > Map Network Drive menu in Windows Explorer. Just specify an IP address if DNS isn't resolving hostnames. You can also do it from the command line:

```
# Map the drive
net use z: \\server\share password:<password> \user:<username>
# Delete the mapping
net use /delete z:
```

Enjoy